# mysql pdo trying to set column to value of uuid() returns "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, uuid

I have build mysql PDO statment for insert like this:

```
insert into user (id_user, email, password, name, uuid) values (:id_user, :email, :password, :name, uuid() )
```

**Note**: *the last uuid() don't have a colon, because I need Mysql executes the function at insert time.*

This returns me the **exception**:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens

How can I pass internal mysql function `"uuid()"` using PDO?

Thank you

Comment: what does uuid() ?

Comment: uuid() function generates an Universal Unique IDentifier, it's a string of 32 chars like

aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A placeholder is not a part of INSERT query syntax, as you probably think.

The SQL syntax, when using PDO prepared statements, **remains exactly the same.** While placeholder have to be used only to represent the external data.

So, as long as you have **four** placeholders in your SQL query, you have to bind exactly **four** variables to your PDO statement.

While any internal function you don't have to "pass" anywhere or bind it. It's already in place, and has no relation to any PDO code.

Comment: Hi everybody, thank your for your fast replies... I got the glue with this reply...

I have a class that build the msql statments, and it was preparing the array of values... ( arr[':field'] = 'value' )

I coded the func to check the array for values, if value matchs the mysql function name, then let that field out...

Thank you a lot

Comment: It is not a good idea and it will crash your code in the future.